# Gradle sync issue with Android Studio 0.5.1

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Since updating to AS 0.5.1, I have been unable to sync up my project. Gradle gives me the following warning:

```
No signature of method: static com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap.create() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: clear(), grep(), get(java.lang.Object), get(java.lang.Object), getAt(java.lang.String), isCase(java.lang.Object)
```

It does not point to anything in my build.gradle file that may be causing the issue, so I am rather lost as to where to begin.

**Edit:** When attempting to run `gradle build`, I subsequently get this issue when applying the Android plugin:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'tve-android'.
> Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
```

My `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url "http://nexus.products/nexus/content/groups/public"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'pmd'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.2"

    defaultConfig.minSdkVersion = 16
    defaultConfig.targetSdkVersion = 19
    defaultConfig.testInstrumentationRunner = 'android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        main.resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
        main.res.srcDirs = ['src/res']
        main.assets.srcDirs = ['src/assets']

        androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
        androidTest.resources.srcDirs = ['src/test/resources']
        androidTest.res.srcDirs = ['src/res']
        androidTest.assets.srcDirs = ['src/assets']
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.+'
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.+'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:disklrucache:1.0.0'
    compile 'net.jpountz.lz4:lz4:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.+'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.+'
}
```

Comment: I suspect that one of your build file plugins is incompatible with the new version of Gradle, or perhaps something else. I tried to test it but couldn't reproduce it. You could isolate the offender by disabling them one-by-one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After further investigation on my part, it seems like a change in the Android build tools may be causing it. Downgrading to 0.4.2 while still keeping the Android Gradle 0.9.+ build tool results in the same warning for me (0.7.+ has no issues). Added an issue to the Android Build Tools issues tracker, and will see how things go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading gradle to v1.10 is also needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I quickly fix it just by re-import my gradle project.